# What is the difference between these two different jqGrids?

Tags: jqgrid

I just started using the jqGrid. I have come across two different types of jqGrids as below.

one looks like below

```
  <trirand:JQGrid ID="Jqgrid3" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="OrderID" PrimaryKey="True" />
        <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Freight" Editable="true" />
        <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="OrderDate" Editable="true"/> 
        <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="ShipCity" Editable="true" />
        </Columns>
    </trirand:JQGrid>
```

and the other one something looks like below

```
       $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: ResolveUrl() + '/DoctorList',
        datatype: 'local',
        postData: { "searchText": searchText },
        mtype: 'POST',
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        serializeGridData: function (jsondata) { return JSON.stringify(jsondata); },
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", 
                     total: "d.total", records: "d.records" },
        colNames: ['Add', 'DoctorID', 'Last Name', 'First Name', 'Address'],
        colModel: [
    { name: 'AddAction', width: 80, fixed: true, 
      sortable: false, resize: false, align: "center" },
    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 50, sortable: false, hidden: false },
    { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 100, 
      hidden: false, frozen: true, sortable: false },
    { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 100, hidden: 
      false, frozen: true, sortable: false },

    { name: 'Address', width: 420, hidden: false, sortable: false,
        jsonmap: function (obj) {
            var street = obj.Address.Address1
            var city = obj.Address.City
            var state = obj.Address.StateProvince
            var zip = obj.Address.PostalCode

            if (street != '') { street = street + ', ' }
            if (city != '') { city = city + ', ' }
            if (state != '') { state = state + ', ' }

            var Address = street + city + state + zip
            return Address
        }
    }],
```

For the previous type I can do some thing like this in codebehind

Jqgrid3.DataSource = GetTable()
        Jqgrid3.DataBind()

I do not know if there is a way to access the cclist jqGrid from the code behind page.
Can some one please help me understand how do I understand the above two different types and are there any advantages over the other and what scenarios they are suited best?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 4):

Your first grid is the purchased version that includes wrappers methods to simplify working with the grid, especially if you are unfamiliar with Jquery/Javascript. Also it comes with a support package, and an additional suite of components.

[Developer Explanation](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=932):

> jqGrid is and will always be licensed under the most permissive and
>   free MIT license. However, many customers and organizations require
>   commercial grade licenses, support and features. This is why we
>   launched our official commercial website http://www.trirand.net. We
>   decided to keep both sites separate, so that there is less confusion
>   for customers.
>
> We started with jqGrid and built a whole suite of components called
>   jqSuite for 3 different platforms – PHP, ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET
>   MVC. These components include HTML5 charts, treeviews, form builders,
>   schedulers and many more. In addition to pure HTML5/Javascript
>   functionality, they are strongly tied to their respective platform and
>   feature powerful server-side API, binding to various datasources,
>   codeless support for many data providers like Oracle, MySQL, MS SQL
>   and many others. This comes with full commercial support, guaranteed
>   responses, active forums with more than 10,000 posts (as of today) and
>   written and supported by the very same guys that created jqGrid. In
>   fact, your questions will be answered only by developers that created
>   the respective product.
>
> Our commercial licensing is pretty simple and straight-forward – “per
>   developer” licensing with unlimited everything (no limit on servers,
>   projects, time, etc). Just the number of developers on the team
>   working with the products. Prices are reasonable and can save you
>   months of development time.

The second [grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) is the free version and is better suited for those familiar with Jquery/Javascript. There is a [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) and [demos](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) available that are of a great help, and a little Googling and you can find many examples of the server side code in any supported language.

Performance wise the grids are pretty much identical, and it just boils down to ease of use for you the developer, and whether or not you need the extra components and support..

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me understand. So Trirand.net is for licensed version and Trirand.com is for a non licensed version of jqGrid? We are using some thing like the second jqGrid , 

 $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: ResolveUrl() + '/DoctorList',
        datatype: 'local', .... So this may be non licensed version and may need a lot of cooking with jquery and javascript then.